# Doxygen thinks C++ class is Objective-C

Tags: doxygen, objective-c++

I just pulled the latest doxygen from [github](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen), compiled it on my Mac, and ran it on a mix of Objective-C and C++ in `.mm` files. For some of the the C++ classes, the output HTML makes the methods look like Objective-C.  For example, code like:

```
void Thing::foo(int x)
```

Is shown in the HTML like:

```
- (void) foo (int) x
```

Any way to fix this?

**Update**

It appears that a forward declared Objective-C class causes a problem.  For example, something like this, in a .h file:

```
@class NSMutableString;
...
class Thing {
  public:
    int foo(double x);
}
```

Causes it to render the `Thing` methods like Objective C.  I cut that one line `@class NSMutableString` and it renders correctly like C++ functions.

C++ classes in .mm files are rendering like Objective-C all the time.

Comment: Does your project for the affected classes happen to have a definition with that name in both C++ and Objective-C?

Comment: I don't see any. It's happening in a lot of classes; some with pretty long, unique names.